"No sentence-transformers model found with name" on huggingface even though it exists
I am trying to use infgrad/stella-base-en-v2 on hugging to generate embeddings using langchain

The model exists on the huggingface hub
The model is listed on the MTEB leaderboard
The model has sentence transformer tag on it

Still when I try to use it like so:
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = "infgrad/stella-base-en-v2")

I get the warning:
No sentence-transformers model found with name infgrad/stella-base-en-v2. Creating a new one with MEAN pooling.

Why is that the case?
